# Не работает всплывающее окно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю модальное окно на jquery, но что-то оно не работает...всплывающее окно со словом "Hello" появляется с самого начала и не исчезает при нажатии на кнопку Click... консоль браузера ошибок не обнаружила

my_script.js

```
$('.show_popup').click(function () {
    var popup_id = $('#' + $(this).attr("rel"));
    $(popup_id).show();
    $('.overlay_popup').show();
})
$('.overlay_popup').click(function () {
    $('.overlay_popup, .popup').hide();
})
```

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_style.css">
    <script
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="my_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <button class="show_popup blue_btn" rel="popup1">Click</button>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay_popup"></div>

    <div class="popup" id="popup1">
       <div class="object">
          <h1>Hello!</h1>      
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так он и не должен исчезать при нажатии на Click. Исчезание у вас забиндено на оверлей

Comment: @Cheg  я делал по видео, на котором данный код при нажатии на button выводил модальное окно...вот я и не пойму ЧТО именно у меня не так

Comment: @Cheg в самом начале НЕ должно быть слова "Hello", оно должно появляться при нажатии на "Click", а прятаться уже при нажатии на оверлей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно прописать необходимый стили, чтобы изначально скрыть `.popup` и `.overlay_popup`:

```js
$('.show_popup').click(function() {
  var popup_id = $('#' + $(this).attr("rel"));
  $(popup_id).show();
  $('.overlay_popup').show();
})
$('.overlay_popup').click(function() {
  $('.overlay_popup, .popup').hide();
})
```

```css
.popup,
.overlay_popup {
  display: none;
}

.overlay_popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <button class="show_popup blue_btn" rel="popup1">Click</button>
</div>

<div class="overlay_popup"></div>

<div class="popup" id="popup1">
  <div class="object">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```